# Python - importing package classes into console global namespace

Tags: python, import, console, namespaces, global

I'm having a spot of trouble getting my python classes to work within the python console. I want to automatically import all of my classes into the global namespace so I can use them without any prefix.module.names.

Here's what I've got so far...

```
projectname/
|-__init__.py
|
|-main_stuff/
  |-__init__.py
  |-main1.py
  |-main2.py
  |
  |-other_stuff/
    |-__init__.py
    |-other1.py
    |-other2.py
```

Each file defines a class of the same name, e.g. main1.py will define a class called Main1.

My `PYTHONPATH` is the absolute path to projectname/.

I've got a python startup file that contains this:

```
from projectname import *
```

But this doesn't let me use my classes at all. Upon starting a python console I would like to be able to write:

```
ob=Main1()
```

but Main1 isn't within the current namespace, so it doesn't work.

I tried adding things to the `__init__.py` files...

In `projectname/__init__.py`:

```
import main_stuff
```

In `projectname/main_stuff/__init__.py`:

```
import other_stuff
__all__ = ["main1", "main2", "main3"]
```

And so on. And in my startup file I added:

```
from projectname.main_stuff import *
from projectname.main_stuff/other_stuff import *
```

But to use the classes within the python console I still have to write:

```
ob=main1.Main1()
```

I'd prefer not to need the `main1.` part. Does anyone know how I can automatically put my classes in the global namespace when using the python console?

Thanks.

==== EDIT ====

What I need is to import a package at the class level, but `from package import *` gives me everything at the module level. I'm after an easy way of doing something like this:

```
for module in package do:
    from package.module import *
```

==== ANOTHER EDIT ====

I ended up adding the class imports to my python startup file individually. It's not ideal because of the overhead of maintaining it, but it does what I want.

```
from class1.py import Class1
from class2.py import Class2
from class3.py import Class3
```

Answer (score 21):

You want to use a different form of import.

In `projectname/main_stuff/__init__.py`:

```
from other_stuff import *
__all__ = ["main1", "main2", "main3"]
```

When you use a statement like this:

```
import foo
```

You are defining the name foo in the current module.  Then you can use `foo.something` to get at the stuff in foo.

When you use this:

```
from foo import *
```

You are taking all of the names defined in foo and defining them in this module (like pouring a bucket of names from foo into your module).